# Integer to Double variable

Tags: java, arrays, variables, integer, double

I need to create a program that will prompt the user to enter salaries and get the highest and lowest salaries.. Ive been working on it for 4 days now.. and I finally created my program using some of the tutorials on the internet but I only have one problem... I just can't convert the INT to Double @*@ its giving me a headache.. where did I go wrong? can someone help me? I need to pass java class ;*;

here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HighestLowestSalary 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many salary do you want to enter?: ");
        int sal = input.nextInt();

        //starting here should be double already..
        System.out.println("Enter the "+sal +" salaries");
        int[]salary = new int[sal];

        for (int i=0; i<sal; i++)
        {
            salary[i]=input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("The Highest Salary is: " +high(salary));
        System.out.println("The Lowest Salary is: " +low(salary));
    }

    public static int high(int[] numbers)
    {
        int highsal = numbers[0];
        for (int i=1; i<numbers.length;i++){
            if (numbers[i] > highsal){
                highsal = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return highsal;
    }

    public static int low(int[] numbers){
        int lowsal = numbers[0];
        for (int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
            if (numbers[i] < lowsal){
                lowsal = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return lowsal;
    }

}
```

anyone who can help me and teach me how to convert it in double? thank you in advance..

Comment: Don't say "Double" when you mean "double", or "Integer" when you mean "int".  The capitalized forms are class names (the primitive wrapper classes) ... and you are not using them anywhere in your code.

Comment: Why would you want to store someone's salary as a `double`?  If it's a whole number of dollars, then an `int` will suffice.  If it's not a whole number of dollars, then `BigDecimal` is more appropriate than `double`.

Comment: its not in dollar.. and im sorry if I said Double instead of double..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erm ... to convert an `int` to a `double` you can just assign it.  The assignment will cause a a "primitive widening conversion" to occur; see [JLS 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

```
int myInt = 42;
double myDouble = myInt;  // converts to a double.
```

(No typecast is necessary for a primitive widening conversion ... though adding one does not harm.)

To convert an int array to a double array ....

```
int[] myInts = ....
double[] myDoubles = new double[myInts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++) {
    myDoubles[i] = myInts[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just assign an int value to double like:

```
int n = 1;
double j = n;
System.out.println(j);
Output:
1.0
```

Note: you could ask for salary to be of double type by using `nextDouble` api instead of `nextInt`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem because of your help! here is what I did.. like everyone said to convert int to Double

```
//this is where I changed all the int to double  

    System.out.println("Enter the "+sal +" salaries");
    double[]salary = new double[sal];

    for (int i = 0; i<sal; i++){
     salary[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.println("The Highest Salary is: " +high(salary));

    System.out.println("The Lowest Salary is: " +low(salary));
}

public static double high(double[] numbers)
{
 double highsal = numbers[0];
 for (int i=1; i<numbers.length;i++){
     if (numbers[i] > highsal){
         highsal = numbers[i];
     }
 }
return highsal;
}

public static double low(double[] numbers){
    double lowsal = numbers[0];
    for (int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
        if (numbers[i] < lowsal){
            lowsal = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return lowsal;
}
}
```